# Getting LaTeX to ignore a number in \include

Tags: errors, include

I am writing a book (using Memoir class in LaTeX if it matters). One of the chapters is titled

> RT_June_13

when I put

> \include{RT_June_13}

in my main file, and then PDF it (using WinEdt, if it matters) I get a message that LaTeX is inserting a $ because it thinks the chapter name is a number.

Is there a way to get this to work properly?

(As an aside, this seems like a weird way for LaTeX to work. Why would I want a number of this sort in a chapter name?)

Comment: latex probably complains about the underscore, use `RT\_June\_13`  in the \chapter command (not in the \include, in file names it is ok to use _

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thanks!